# why should i make the returned instance of factory a static field?

Tags: flutter, factory

Creating a function that returns an instance of the class is right, but creating a factory that returns an instance of the class should be a static field. why should i make the returned instance of factory a static field?

**the code is:**

```
class DBHelper{
  DBHelper._();
  factory DBHelper()=>instance; // ->> cursor error
   // static
  // final  
  DBHelper instance=DBHelper._();
  int number=2;
  int fun()=>number;
}
```

Comment: make your reply as an answer to accept it, thanks a lot @pskink

Comment: write a self answer then ;-)

Comment: i said that to give you points :) @pskink

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't quite get the purpose of factory methods. The example you've posted is the way of using singleton pattern in dart/flutter. It's, in my opinion the cleanest way of creating a singleton class.

Now the factory method can be used to to simplify the construction of objects and they don't have to return static fields at all. Here are a few examples:

```
class OneObject {
  final int one;
  final String two;
  final double three;

  OneObject(this.one, this.two, this.three);
  
  factory OneObject.withoudTwo(int one, double three) {
    return OneObject(one, "2", three);
  }
  
  factory OneObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> aMap) {
    return OneObject(aMap["one"], aMap["two"], aMap["three"]); // this is bad use of json parsing
  }
}
```

In your case the `DBHelper._();` is the actual constructor of the class and the `_` makes it private and this allows you to create a factory method called `DBHelper.();`

To elaborate the answer a bit more, factory methods are similar to static methods and static methods can't access instance members of the class that they are declared on, they can access only static members. In your example, the `instance` property (without static) will be created only when a new instance of the DbHelper is created and because of that, returning it from a factory method is impossible because it's not available yet.

Comment: i knew that is way called singleton. if you create an in stance of your your class you will not be able to return it outside any factory. 
you have returned a constructor, not an instance.
but also you can return an instance in case of make it a static.
my question is why that happening? @danypata

Comment: @Mariam did my edit clarify your question ?